# Unwanted margin around grid layout

Tags: html, css

Help me understand what exactly creates the margins around the layout.
I assume this is how grid display behaves?

I tried negative margin and it worked for left and top but has created space on the right.

```
.container {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        min-height: 300px;
        width: 100%;
        background: LightGray;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto;
        grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
        grid-template-areas:
          "welcome-section"
          "projects"
          "footer";
      }
      #welcome-section {

        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: auto;
        background: black;
        grid-area: welcome-section;
      }
      #projects {
        background: PaleTurquoise;
        grid-area: projects;
      }

      #footer {
        background: lightpink;
        grid-area: footer;
      }
    </style>

    <div class="container">

      <div id="welcome-section">
        <h1></h1>
      </div>

      <div id="projects">
        <div class="project-tile"></div>
        <div class="project-tile"></div>
      </div>

      <div id="footer"></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: try setting the margin of your body to 0: (body has margins by default)
`body{ margin: 0;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `body` tag. By default it has margins.

Try:

```
Body{
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `height: 100%;` instead of `height: 100vh;` inside the css of the **#welcome-section**:

```css
.container {
        
        font-size: 1.5em;
        min-height: 300px;
        width: 100%;
        background: LightGray;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto;
        grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
        grid-template-areas:
          "welcome-section"
          "projects"
          "footer";
      }
      #welcome-section {

        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        background: black;
        grid-area: welcome-section;
      }
      #projects {
        background: PaleTurquoise;
        grid-area: projects;
      }

      #footer {
        background: lightpink;
        grid-area: footer;
      }
```

```html
<div class="container">

      <div id="welcome-section">
        <h1></h1>
      </div>

      <div id="projects">
        <div class="project-tile"></div>
        <div class="project-tile"></div>
      </div>

      <div id="footer"></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Does not do anything so I went with view height